# Rails Ajax Route not Changing Style

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an AJAX route which is meant to create a user_fav_store_item instance and update the style of a button.

Here is my button:

```
<td><%=button_to "♥",add_fav_item_from_search_path(:user_id=>@current_user.id, :store_item_id =>s.id),:id=>"SI"+ s.id.to_s, :remote=>true%></td>
```

And here is my route:

```
  post 'add_fav_item_from_search' => 'user_fav_store_items#change_fav_on_search'
```

Controller action:

```
def change_fav_on_search
@user_fav_store_item=UserFavStoreItem.new(:user_id=>params[:user_id], :store_item_id => params[:store_item_id])
@user_fav_store_item.save
@store_item_id = params[:store_item_id]
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

end
And view:

```
$("#SI<%=@store_item_id%>").style="color:white;background-color:red";
```

I know that the FavStoreItem records are being made. And I know that the route is trying to load the page, since I spent a while dealing with errors, yet now it is running smoothly except that the style is not updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery css selector

```
$("#SI<%=@store_item_id%>").css({
    color:white,
    background-color:red
});
```

[jQuery CSS Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Didn't help...The color still remains unchanged